# Identifying range overlap

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary of dictionaries that describe a person's name and date of birth and date of death.

```
var people = [ "Michael": [ "birth": 1900, "death" : 1975 ], "John": [ "birth": 1973, "death" : 2000 ], "Julian": [ "birth": 1950, "death" : 1985 ] ]
```

I would like to determine what years all members were simultaneously alive.

Here is my rather brute and unscalable implementation:

```
var years = [Int]()
var overlap = [Int]()    
var overlapTwice = [Int]()
var overlapThree = [Int]()

for life in people.values {
    var birth = Int(life["birth"]!)
    var death = Int(life["death"]!)

    for year in birth..<death {
        if !years.contains(year) {
            years.append(year)
        } else {
            overlap.append(year)
        }
    }
}

for x in overlap {
    if !overlapTwice.contains(x) {
        overlapTwice.append(x)
    } else {
        overlapThree.append(x)
    }
}
print(overlapThree)
```

I would like to know the right way to solve this problem, as mine would obviously require writing a loop for every additional range

Comment: Are you looking for `1973-1975` given the data you posted? What should happen is there isn't a common range for everyone in the list?

Comment: Why not do a single loop getting the max birth and min death. Done.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes 1973-1975 is what I'm looking for. How would the max birth/death loop work ?

Comment: @rmaddy Wanted to say the same ;) Also OP should probably revise data structures, as this is a horrible way of storing stuff, generally you want to avoid strings, use a named tuple instead.

Comment: @kametrixom Why do you want to avoid strings? memory? and thanks for the tip

Comment: @rayperry Memory is one thing, your dictionary would have to store the strings "birth" and "death" for every person. Also typos: If you wrote "birht" once, your app would crash. Also avoid dictionaries for things like that, you can use a tuple instead (look at my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a much simpler way to solve this. Do a single loop. Keep track of the maximum birth year and the minimum death year. That will be your range.

If max birth ends up greater than min death then there is no overlap.

The following is written mostly as pseudo-code since I am not fluent in Swift:

```
var maxBirth = 0 // start with small value
bar minDeath = 9999 // start with large value
for life in people.values {
    var birth = Int(life["birth"]!)
    var death = Int(life["death"]!)

    if birth > maxBirth {
        maxBirth = birth
    }
    if death < minDeath {
        minDeath = death
    }
}
```

Your overlap range will be from maxBirth to minDeath.

Answer (score 1):

As @rmaddy already mentioned, you can just get the range from the maximum birth year to the minimum death year. I suggest however to change your data structure, as it's not safe and typos can happen:

```
typealias Person = (name : String, lifeRange : Range<Int>)

let people : [Person] = [
    ("Michael", 1900..<1973),
    ("John", 1973..<2000),
    ("Julian", 1950..<1985)
]

func commonYearRange(people: [Person]) -> Range<Int>? {
    guard let
        minYear = people.map({ $0.lifeRange.startIndex }).maxElement(),
        maxYear = people.map({ $0.lifeRange.endIndex }).minElement()
    where minYear <= maxYear else { return nil }

    return minYear..<maxYear
}

commonYearRange(people)     // 1973..<1975
```

Comment: Yes but I need to refer to the birth value in my program

Comment: @rayperry You can, like this: `people.lifeRange.startIndex`. Of course you can just save start and end separately, to use `Range` just makes it easier to reason about, because that's really what it is